# Content Security Policy connect-src sources 'unsafe-inline' and 'unsafe-eval'

Tags: javascript, html, content-security-policy

I'm trying to sort out in what situation the sources 'unsafe-inline' and 'unsafe-eval' would be needed on the `connect-src` directive. They are listed here as sources:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/connect-src

It seems clear to me why these sources would be needed on `script-src`, I just can not piece together why they would be necessary for `connect-src` - and I'm assuming there must be a reason for MDN to list them as sources on this directive.

Can someone help me understand or give me the use case? Take the example below. Notice that I'm successfully making a GET request to mocky.io from an inline script, and then calling eval() w/in the callback WITHOUT the 'unsafe-inline' or 'unsafe-eval' source for the `connect-src` directive.

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src https://run.mocky.io;">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Testing CSP</h1>
    
    <!-- testing any JS executing from unsafe inline -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    console.log("Testing some unsafe inline");
    </script>
    
    <!-- testing XHR calls from unsafe inline -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    const callMocky = () => {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                //eval from the XHR state change
                eval("console.log('XHR Sent and Received!')")
                console.log(xhttp.responseText);

            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "https://run.mocky.io/v3/7ef12b35-8438-424f-8a5f-b11521d03fe7", true);
        xhttp.send();
    }

    callMocky()
    </script>

    <!-- testing unsafe eval from unsafe inline -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        eval('console.log("this is an unsafe eval!")')
    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Looks to me like a c&p'ed page on MDN. There's a "Report Problem" link at the bottom of the page. Try to ask your question there.

Comment: That's how `connect-src` is defined in the spec; the value is allowed to be any [`serialized-source-list`](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#grammardef-serialized-source-list), and `serialized-source-list` includes `keyword-source`, and `keyword-source` includes `"'unsafe-inline'" / "'unsafe-eval'"`.

Comment: The URL to mocky.io passes the `connect-src` defined in your CSP. The `script-src` does not affect the URLs allowed for connections. If you were to do something like `xhr.open("GET", "javascript:eval(\"https://run.mocky.io/...\")")` or `var url = "https://run.mocky.io/..."; xhr.open("GET", "javascript:url");` CSP might block those...

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Didn't think to check the spec. I'm noticing that the spec references `unsafe-inline` and `unsafe-eval` in the pre and post-check for `script-src`, but they are not mentioned in the `connect-src` directive. - I'm wondering if syntactically it's correct with `connect-src` since they are from the source list, but that they wouldn't serve a purpose.  Tried your suggestion above and couldn't get a meaningful result. Could be user error :)